# What output file do I need for this effect on Sketchfab?

Tags: blend4web

what approach do I need to take to make a web-based viewing experience like this?

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/card-480f67a65e7f463bb5bc1b6d26f3c5ce

I understand how to make the effect, but I have no idea what output files I need for this viewing experience.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Just look at the model from the top. It's a zig zag mesh, one side holds the image seen from the left and the other holds the image seen from the right. So two textures, one put on one half of the faces, the other on the other half.

Answer (score 1):

> what output files I need for this viewing experience.

Export as obj or fbx, the usual. It's nothing more than a mesh after all.
Your Mesh(es) (.obj, fbx, etc.) + eventual libraries (.mtl,etc.), your textures (2 in this case) and that's all. Drag and drop those files in Sketchfab's upload webpage. And it will do the rest.

> I understand how to make the effect, but I have no idea what output files [...]

You understand how it's made? Then make it. I don't really see what's your issue here.